# Change the frame afer the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added UIView at some angle. Now at the run time i want to move that view to up (say 20px).

**At start**

```
 dragView = [[DragbleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 200, 90)];
dragView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (-0.663247);
```

**At Run Time**

```
  NSLog(@"Before : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(dragView.frame));
[dragView setCenter:CGPointMake(dragView.frame.origin.x, dragView.center.y+20)];
NSLog(@"After : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(dragView.frame));
```

**Console O/p**

```
Before : {{3.4947295778412979, 147.97225037436704}, {213.0105408443174, 194.05549925126593}}
After : {{-103.0105408443174, 167.97225037436704}, {213.0105408443174, 194.05549925126593}}
```

As you can see it goes to the wrong place. How to place above 20 px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing as you have specified. You would get better results using the center point for both the X and Y:

```
[dragView setCenter:CGPointMake(dragView.center.x, dragView.center.y + 20)];
```

Also, as noted below. iOS uses 0,0 as top left, so to move something "up" would require subtracting 20 from the dragView.center.y.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the docs on the UIView frame property, they say:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of
>   this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

So you can't change the frame once you've changed your view's transform. It doesn't work any more.

Instead you should use the view's center property, as @GaryRiches suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

To move UP, it requires to minimize Y location values, whereas you are adding.

Try this:

```
[dragView setCenter:CGPointMake(dragView.frame.origin.x, dragView.center.y - 20)];
```